# Indents in python 3

Tags: python

I'm new to python and would like to know when to use indents. I understand them in 'if' functions, as it denotes that the next line is part of this if function. Is there a limit to how many indents can be used or do the indents just have to make up to the previous number of indents used in the function.

In the code below could the print function be indented further? Would that align the function with the code aligned above this if statement.

In essence is there a rule for indenting/ best practice for a beginner

cheers

```
if word.rstrip("\n").startswith("e"):

length = len(word.rstrip("\n"))

print(length)
```

Comment: indentation works same as curly brackets in other programming languages, you have to indent everything, like after if in your code you have not indent length that will give error

Comment: For questions are about style and functionality, I would start with the python PEP8 guide on indentation: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Comment: The highlights from PEP8 https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#intermezzo-coding-style

Comment: `could the print function be indented further?` did you try it? What happened?. With an interpreted language is that it is easy to test things like this.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python allows to give more than one space(minimum one space) for indentation. And we have to give same spaces(INDENTATION) for rest codes of same loop or conditional statement.

Example:

```
if(1==1):
    print("IN IF CONDITION")
    print("GIVE SAME SPACES")
print("OUT OF IF CONDITION")
```